# Is there a way to re-install the default Magento theme?

Tags: magento

I inherited a Magento store from another developer who tried to customize the default theme and made a mess of things. I'd like to install a fresh template but need the default theme back in its' original form (without the customizations/modifications made by the previous guy). There are no backups available for me to roll back to.

Is there any way I can download and re-install the original, unaltered Magento default theme, or do I need to start with a fresh installation of Magento to obtain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution that I know that comes out of the box regarding templates rollback (as there is not for rolling back sql table schemas...).

You can get the version of the Magento via `Mage::getVersion()` and it should also be displayed in the footer of the admin panel.

From there, you can download any version of Magento from Magento's website and overwrite the whole directory app/design/frontend/default/default and/or app/design/frontend/default/base depending on the version.

You don't have to get the whole Magento to a fresh install... But chances are, that if the template is that a mess, you could also have to deal with core files modification (the worst) and may want to actually start from a fresh Magento install.